# React-JS: Access a child's method through HOC wrapper

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an `Editor` component that looks like so:

```
class EditorComp extends Component {
  focus() {
    this.refs.input.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input 
        ref="input"
        ...
      />
    );
  }
}
```

So that elements that use `EditorComp` can set a ref and call its `focus` method and apply focus to the lower level input, like so:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.refs.editor.focus()}>Focus</button>
        <EditorComp ref="editor" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However, when wrapping `EditorComp` in a Higher Order Component (like `react-redux`'s `connect()`) the `EditorComp` loses the focus method because it gets trapped underneath the HOC.

Example:

```
const WrappedEditor = connect()(EditorComp); // react-redux's connect, for example
const wrappedEditorInstance = <WrappedEditor />;

wrappedEditorInstance.focus() // Error! Focus is not a function.
```

Is there a way to pass up method or component references through the parent HOCs of a child component?

---

Edit: Or is there a reverse solution in which the parent hands down a function which sets the focus command? I've considered using an `event-emitter`, and having the child listen to a `focus` event called by the parent, however this seems unwieldy and unnecessary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1 way return comp instance**

```
class EditorComp extends Component {
  focus() {
    this.refs.input.focus();
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.onMount(this)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        ref="input"
        ...
      />
    );
  }
}
export default connect(state=>({state}), actions)(EditorComp);


class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.editor.focus()}>Focus</button>
        <EditorComp  onMount={c=>this.editor=c}  ref="editor" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**2 way pass down position**

```
class EditorComp extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    let {input}= this.refs
    this.props.isFocus? input.focus():input.blur();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        ref="input"
        ...
      />
    );
  }
}
export default connect(state=>({state}), actions)(EditorComp);


class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({isfocus:true});}>Focus</button>
        <EditorComp  isFocus={this.state.isfocus}  ref="editor" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The `1 way return comp instance` is near perfect, however it looks like the `2 way pass down position` may not work as intended. The `EditorComp` will try to steal focus anytime it updates as long as `this.props.isfocus === true`. That probably can be dealt with, but It should be noted.

Thanks again!